# How do I use an SQS queue in one CloudFormation stack as a trigger to a lambda function in another CloudFormation stack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sqs, aws-serverless

[image]

**What I did so far**: I exported the Arn of the Queue and the QueueName from the stack where the queue is created and used them in the Events under the lambda function which I want to trigger and also defined the QueuePolicy in that stack to get the permissions to ReceiveMessage from the queue.

This approach is working when I first build both the stacks but the next time when I build, it is disabling the trigger under the Lambda triggers in the SQS queue definition. I was never successful in seeing it as a trigger under the lambda function.

Let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Can you share the Cloudformation templates for both of the stacks? How do you "build" them?

Answer (score 0):

You can call the cloudformation stack action (create/update/delete...) with the `NotificationArns` option.

This will send a message for each stack resources event. Then it gives the habilities to trigger lambda.

The message follows this kind of payload :

```
{
    "Records": [
        {
            "EventSource": "aws:sns",
            "EventVersion": "1.0",
            "EventSubscriptionArn": "arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:12345678912:my-sns-topic:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "Sns": {
                "Type": "Notification",
                "MessageId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:eu-west-0:000000000000:my-sns-topic",
                "Subject": "AWS CloudFormation Notification",
                "Message": "
                    StackId='${STACK_ID}'\n
                    Timestamp='2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z'\n
                    EventId='00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'\n
                    LogicalResourceId='${STACK_NAME}'\n
                    Namespace='000000000000'\n
                    PhysicalResourceId='${STACK_ID}'\n
                    PrincipalId='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTU:1234567890123456789'\n
                    ResourceProperties='null'\
                    ResourceStatus='${RESOURCE_STATUS}'\n
                    ResourceStatusReason=''\n
                    ResourceType='AWS::CloudFormation::Stack'\n
                    StackName='${STACK_NAME}'\n
                    ClientRequestToken='null'\n
                ",
                "Timestamp": "2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                "SignatureVersion": "1",
                "Signature": "_",
                "SigningCertUrl": "_",
                "UnsubscribeUrl": "_",
                "MessageAttributes": {}
            }
        }
    ]
}
```